# How do I protect ContentResolver from being accessed by just any app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

Android newbie here.

I'm starting to learn about ContentProviders and I've set up my first ContentProvider which internally accesses a private SQLiteOpenHelper class to read and write data out of my database.

I take it one of the main benefits of ContentProviders is that you put all your data accessing code in the one place and the only time you're supposed to access the database is via ContentResolvers which use the ContentProvider's URI? [correct me if i'm wrong, i just figure that is the case as all the examples put SQLiteOpenHelper as a private class]

So I've recently written an update method in my ContentProvider which clears a column in my database. It looks roughly like this

```
    @Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,
        String[] whereArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    int count;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {

    case FACT_ID:
        String segment = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
        count = database.update(TABLE_FACT, values,
                KEY_ID
                        + "="
                        + segment
                        + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(where) ? " AND (" + where
                                + ')' : ""), whereArgs);
        break;
    case CLEAR_DATESEEN:
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.putNull(KEY_DATESEEN);
        count = database.update(TABLE_FACT, cv, null, null);

        break;

    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
```

The CLEAR_DATESEEN bit of the code is the one that clears the column.

This works but I was just wondering, doesn't this mean that any app on the device that calls that URI should be able to clear that column as well? What if I did not want other apps messing with my data?

Is there any way to prevent certain apps or only allow certain apps to be able to call my ContentProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have set-up a [special permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) and provide that information to other apps (developers), your content provider is accessible only for your app. Please see [Content Provider Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Permissions).

Comment: ah ok, well didn't realize that existed!

Comment: Isn't there even a way to detect which app requested the content?